# How do I find a row in bootstrap-tables without using getRowByUniqueId

Tags: bootstrap-table

In Bootstrap-Tables I can use getRowByUniqueId to find and return a row.

Is there a way to find a row using other columns values? e.g.:

```
var row = $table.bootstrapTable('getRowByColumnValues', { "col1": "abc", "col2": 5 });
```